# How to fix ipaddress in CentOS?

Tags: centos

I am using VMWare 10, in that installed CentOS 6.5 with two networking interfaces (eth0,eth1).

When I try to use the vmware, every time the ipaddress changes.

How to make the IP address constant (not a static IP address)?

Comment: What do you mean by a "constant" but not "static" IP address?

Comment: Means ipaddreess is keep on changing...i am using another vm ,in that ipaddress is constant...how do i fix this issue....

Comment: How is the IP address configured on that other VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vmware will by default allocate dhcp ip addesses. In order to have static IP address, please assign static IP address in Centos using below steps

Static IP assignment for eth0

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

Sample output:
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
HWADDR="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="no"
TYPE="Ethernet"
```

Configure eth0:
In above you can look that IP address is assigned dynamically using dhcp. Change this to below, make sure you aren't changing hwaddr, device - leave it unchanged.

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
IPADDR=192.168.1.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0

service network restart
```

It will work now.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh..........yeah it will work ,i know but eth0 is dynamic in another vm the ip address is never changed(192.168.17.140 so many time i restarted).my vm only change the ip address , any specific reason ...

Comment: There will be default lease period for each allocated IP. You can assign different IP to current VM for solving this issue.